# How to merge LINQ querys of lambdas which return of anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, union

I'm trying to combine 2 lists from these:

```
var quartEst = Quarterly_estimates
.OrderByDescending (q => q.Yyyy)
.ThenByDescending (q => q.Quarter)
.Where (q => 
    q.Ticker.Equals("IBM")
    &&
    q.Eps != null
    )
.Select (q => new {
    ticker = q.Ticker,
    Quarter = q.Quarter,
    Year = q.Yyyy,
    Eps = q.Eps})
.AsEnumerable()
.Where (q => Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{1}", q.Year, q.Quarter)) > Convert.ToInt32(finInfo) );

var quartAct = Quarterlies
.OrderByDescending (q => q.Yyyy)
.ThenByDescending (q => q.Quarter)
.Where (q => 
    q.Ticker.Equals("IBM")
    &&
    Convert.ToInt16(q.Yyyy) >= DateTime.Now.Year - 3
    )
.Select (q => new {
    Tick = q.Ticker,
    Quarter = q.Quarter,
    Year = q.Yyyy,
    Eps = q.Eps_adj})
.AsEnumerable()
.Where (q => Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{1}", q.Year, q.Quarter)) <= Convert.ToInt32(finInfo));
```

I get the error for a simple Union command:

```
var quartComb = quartEst.Union(quartAct);
```

Here's the error:

```
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'
```

What do I need to do to achieve this merge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the `Union` method, the collections must have the same type. In order for two anonymous types to be considered the same, they must have exactly the same members with exactly the same types.

Try this:

```
var quartEst = Quarterly_estimates
    ...
    .Select (q => new {
        Tick = q.Ticker,       // renamed ticker to Tick
        Quarter = q.Quarter,
        Year = q.Yyyy,
        Eps = q.Eps})
    ...

var quartAct = Quarterlies
    .Select (q => new {
        Tick = q.Ticker,
        Quarter = q.Quarter,
        Year = q.Yyyy,
        Eps = q.Eps_adj})
    ...

var quartComb = quartEst.Union(quartAct);
```

Comment: 1+ Or renamed ticker to Ticker?

Comment: @loy yep, that would work, too. It really doesn't matter what the name is as long as it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

To cast two different Anonymous Types you have to cast it to dynamic, Here is the below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<AlertInfo> alert = new List<AlertInfo>();
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 1, GroupId = 1 });
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 1, GroupId = 2 });
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 1, GroupId = 3 });
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 2, GroupId = 1 });
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 2, GroupId = 2 });
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 2, GroupId = 3 });
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 3, GroupId = 1 });
        alert.Add(new AlertInfo() { StratId = 3, GroupId = 2 });

        //To know how much data will get stored
        var totalDataStore = alert.Select(x => x.StratId).Distinct().ToList();

        var result = alert.Where(x => x.StratId == 1).Select(x => new { Data1 = "Group" + x.StratId + x.GroupId }).Cast<dynamic>().Union(alert.Where(y => y.StratId == 2).Select(y => new { Data2 = "Group" + y.StratId + y.GroupId })).ToList();

    }
}

public class AlertInfo
{
    public int StratId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```